# What is the effect of FeedOptions.EnableLowPrecisionOrderBy Property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Azure DocumentDB .NET SDK document querying API provide option to reduce order by precision but the exact expected effect remains vague. The [documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.enablelowprecisionorderby?view=azure-dotnet) only:

> Gets or sets the option to enable low precision order by in the Azure DocumentDB database service.

The [ORDER BY-clause documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-reference#bk_orderby_clause) does not say a word about ordering behavior depending on `FeedOptions` or results being sometimes ordered differently than requested in query.

- What does the mentioned option actually do?
- What precision can we expect when using "low precision"?
- What can we assert about the actual order beyond that "low precision"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB supports varying the precision of your index to reduce the storage footprint of indexing (default is full precision). For example, with a numeric precision of 5, the service would index the first 5 bytes of your number.

By default, sorting a property with a lower precision is disallowed. But you can opt-in to perform an ORDER BY by setting EnableLowPrecisionOrderBy. Let's say you choose a numeric precision of 5 (for an 8-byte number). The query results will be in order based on the most significant 5 bytes of the number, but guarantees no order for the remaining 3 bytes. This option lets you perform fast order by without requiring full precision indexing, for example, when you're performing ad-hoc exploration of data.

For most use cases, you should use the default precision, and not have to rely on the lower precision order by.

**EDIT**: this is now deprecated, and indexing is by default maximum precision

Comment: Makes sense, but what about when ordering by non-indexed property (ad hoc exloration)? Will it default to safer full-precision search (ignoring the option) or faster 0-precison search (ignoring order by)?

Comment: We do not support ordering on a non-indexed property. You will get an error that the path must be indexed.